# ClassNotFoundException with Exe4J

Tags: java, jar, exe4j

I have Packaged my own jre into the exe4J and made an exe file from the jar file of my
Java Application using regular mode of exe4J it runs great on my computer But when i try to double click the exe file on another computer (ex: on my friends machine)
It Gives me an Error Saying

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.falcon.ui.main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

Where "com.falcon.ui" is name of my package and "main" is my class Name

Comment: One of the sections when building an exe is the definition of the class path.  You can either use embedded or linked options.  Embedded means that the required libraries are bundled internally to the exe, when linked is the classic concept of a classpath

Comment: I have done that i mean i have packaged the jre bundle as shown in 6th step under Advanced option search sequence Step also i have inserted my jar file and a lib folder that contains all my useful jar files into the Class Path Under Step 5 of exe 4j it works on my computer but when i take a file on other computer it gives me an error ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Hi cud anybody help me in this

Answer (score 0):

In the **Regular mode**, exe4j is a pure launcher and relies on all JAR files and resources to be present in the distribution. In other words, the exe4j executable is an **addition to your distribution**, and not a replacement for it.

You can use **JAR in EXE** mode, exe4j includes the JAR files specified in the class path configuration of the java invocation step into the executable. In this way, you can **distribute your application as a single executable**.